# How can i use Mvc Label with Html.Raw

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing an application with asp.net mvc

How can i use Mvc Label with Html.Raw.

This my codes but notworking

```
@Html.Label("txtLoginMail", Html.Raw((string)ViewBag.reqRegisterLastName))
```

Comment: What is the reason you want to use `Html.Raw` in this case ?

Comment: What is the value of `reqRegisterLastName`? And what are you attempting to output?

Comment: ViewBag.reqRegisterLastName = "Seçiniz"    but I'm having a special character issue

Comment: Its just `@Html.Label("txtLoginMail", (string)ViewBag.reqRegisterLastName)` and if its not displaying correctly, its an encoding issue. Having `Html.Raw()` inside `Html.Label()` makes no sense

Comment: i agree with Stephen, just save the file in "UTF-8" encoding, you shouldn't need Html.Raw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Stephen and Sedat, the simplest way to do this is using encoding.

```
@{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ViewBag.reqRegisterLastName);
    var reqRegisterLastName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}
@Html.Label("txtLoginMail", reqRegisterLastName)
```